# USBasp not creating ttyUSB0

Tags: udev, ttyusb

I bought an USBASP 2.0 programmer and hooked it up, I cannot see any port created by the programmer. What I expect is `USBtty0` in `/dev`

To fix it I have restarted UDEV and tried other UDEV configurations but it doesn't show.

**uname**

```
Linux Puc 4.4.0-21-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 18 18:33:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**lsusb**

```
Bus 003 Device 092: ID 16c0:05dc Van Ooijen Technische Informatica shared ID for use with libusb
```

**dmesg**

```
[181622.326920] usb 3-5: new low-speed USB device number 92 using xhci_hcd
[181622.460268] usb 3-5: New USB device found, idVendor=16c0, idProduct=05dc
[181622.460270] usb 3-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[181622.460271] usb 3-5: Product: USBasp
[181622.460272] usb 3-5: Manufacturer: www.fischl.de
```

**udev rule**

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTRS{idVendor}=="16c0", ATTRS{idProduct}=="05dc", MODE="0666"
```

this device: 
http://www.fischl.de/usbasp/

[EDIT]

Using this command from the `arduino/hardware/tools/avr` directory, the connection works, just not from within the Arduino IDE.

`./bin/avrdude -C etc/avrdude.conf -c usbasp -P usb -p m328p`

```
avrdude: warning: cannot set sck period. please check for usbasp firmware update.
avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e950f

avrdude: safemode: Fuses OK (H:05, E:DF, L:FF)

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's supposed to.

If I remember correctly, USBasp works with custom control transfers, and e.g. `avrdude` looks it up from `/dev/bus/usb` by the vendor and product IDs and ID strings.

With `avrdude`, something like this should work, or complain that it can't find a USB device with the correct IDs:

```
avrdude -P usb -c usbasp -p $UC
```

Also, since USBasp works with software-implemented USB, it's limited to low-speed operation, which in principle means that it can't work as a serial port:

> The USB CDC class is intended for modems and other communication devices. [...]
>   CDC requires bulk endpoints which are forbidden for low speed devices by the USB specification.

(quote from the [V-USB wiki](http://vusb.wikidot.com/usb-device-classes))

Comment: thanks again, I have edited my question to reflect the lesson learned.